# How to transpose date from column to row with mapping value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a python pandas dataframe like this:

> ```
> id | Client | Type | V1  |  V2 |  V3 |  V4 |
> ---------------------------------------------
> 0  |  John  | Time | 20  | 24  |     |     |
> 0  |  John  |Score |  7  |  8  |     |     |
> 0  |  John  |Level |  A  |  B  |     |     |
> 1  |  Tim   | Time | 15  | 19  |  20 |  18 |
> 1  |  Tim   |Score |  9  |  8  |  6  |  9  |
> 1  |  Tim   |Level |  C  |  A  |  C  |  A  | 
> 2  | Daniel | Time | 17  |     |     |     |
> 2  | Daniel |Score |  7  |     |     |     |
> 2  | Daniel |Level |  B  |     |     |     |
> ```

I would like to transpose into this table:

```
Client | Time |Score | Level 
--------------------------------
 John  |  20  |  7   |  A   |
 John  |  24  |  8   |  B   |
 Tim   |  15  |  9   |  C   |
 Tim   |  19  |  8   |  A   |
 Tim   |  20  |  6   |  C   |
 Tim   |  18  |  9   |  A   |
Daniel |  17  |  7   |  B   |
```

I read some posts using pd.melt or df.stack but it seems my case is a bit different. 
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with removeinf missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with helper Series created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.melt(['id','Client','Type']).dropna(subset=['value'])
g = df.groupby(['Client','Type']).cumcount()
df1 = (df.set_index([g,'Client','Type'])['value'].unstack()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .sort_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Client Level Score Time
0  Daniel     B     7   17
1    John     A     7   20
2    John     B     8   24
3     Tim     C     9   15
4     Tim     A     8   19
5     Tim     C     6   20
6     Tim     A     9   18
```

Answer (score 0):

One way about it is to get the columns as a multiindex, then reshape with a combination of stack and unstack to get ur final output

```
#set index on the first three columns
df = df.set_index(['id','Client','Type'])

#split columns and convert to multiIndex
#wrapping the delimiter(digit) ensures it is part of the final split result
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("(\d)",expand=True).droplevel(-1)
df.columns = df.columns.set_names(['V','numbers'])

res = (df.stack("numbers")
       #get Type as columns
       .unstack("Type")
       #remove irrelevant indexes
       .droplevel(["id", "numbers"])
       .droplevel("V",axis=1)
       .rename_axis(None,axis=1)
      )
res

       Level    Score   Time
Client          
John    A        7       20
John    B        8       24
Tim     C        9       15
Tim     A        8       19
Tim     C        6       20
Tim     A        9       18
Daniel  B        7       17
```